# kotlin-js convert string to another encoding

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I parse site and get String in windows-1251 encoding. I want print it to console for example. But in console I see incomprehensible symbols. How I can convert windows-1251 String to UTF-8 or how I can print normal string using kotlin-js ?

Comment: A String object is *already/always* in Unicode. What is used to populate the string? Conversion from/to different *encodings* should be handled on ingestion (as a String is created from a sequence of bytes) and output (as a String is written as a sequence of bytes) ..

Comment: I used html parser and parser returned string in unreadable format. Is your proposal convert String  to byte array , then decode it and convert to String back ?

Comment: No. The first step is to find out why the parser returned the string in an “unreadable format.”